# Using a value from a dynamic dropdown in a SQL query in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

So I've been working on a form that posts to a mySQL database for a bit now, and I've gotten the bulk of it up and running without much error. That being said, I've been having trouble with my dynamic query. I have a page where the user can update a record in the database and initially they choose a value from a dropdown, submit that value to the database which in turn should populate the form with that value's data from the database. It's working great with a hard-coded value, but making it dynamic means pulling the value from the cfselect tag, and I'm not sure how to do that. I've seen great examples of pulling the data using JS, jQuery and other things, but inserting that into a CFML variable to use in the SQL statement (within the cfquery tags) is proving troublesome.

**Here's my query block:**

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, 'lookup')>
<cfquery name="foundRecord" datasource="database">
    SELECT * FROM events
    WHERE event_id = <!---The dynamic variable would go here--->
</cfquery>
<cfoutput>
    <cfform>                            
        <!---Form with inputs to be populated--->
    </cfform>
</cfoutput>
```

**And my dropdown:**

```
<cfquery name="eventNameList" datasource="database">
     SELECT event_id, event_name, date
     FROM events
     ORDER BY date ASC
</cfquery>
<cfform>
    <fieldset class="form">
    <br>
         <cfselect name="event_name" id="event_name" query="eventNameList" value="event_id" display="event_name" queryPosition="below">
              <option value="0">Please choose your event</option>
         </cfselect>
         <br><br>
         <button type="submit" class="button" name="lookup" id="lookup">Find Record</button>
    </fieldset>
</cfform>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Use `<cfdump var="#form#">` to inspect what the POST request contains. You'll spot your selected option in `event_name`. Access the value via `form["event_name"]`. And then have a read about [`<cfqueryparam>`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/accessing-and-using-data/accessing-and-retrieving-data/enhancing-security-with-cfqueryparam.html).

Comment: My first observation is don't use cfform stuff. In generally, I discourage devs from using CFML functions (like cfform stuff) that injects front-end code into the DOM output. It's buggy and difficult to debug. You'll need to use <cfqueryparam value="#form.idValue#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_...."> where your dynamic variable goes. It's important to use cfparam because it sanitizes the variable to ensure someone can't hack into your database. Get your variable from either the Form or URL scope depending on the method used in your Form (POST = Form scope, GET = URL scope).

Comment: Thanks gents! A combination of the 2 of your comments worked absolutely beautifully. Many thanks!